# HTML code only works fine on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, web

My HTML code only works fine on Chrome (I built it using it), when I try to open it with any other browsers (IE, Edge, Firefox) it seems different, the size of the images are not the same, as the size of the text is, the videos are showing an error and cannot be played, the alignment is so wrong and generally the whole page looks terrible! I don't use any CSS so I can't actually find what is wrong!
In addition, it's quite strange that when Chrome isn't already running (there aren't any tabs open) and I open my site it doesn't look completely right, it's like everything is zoomed, even the buttons and menu in Chrome.
What is wrong? What can I do?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icon.png"/>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body background="bg.png" link="white">
<img src="Banner.png">
<table align="center" valign="top" bgcolor="rgb(0,0,51)" style="width:100%">
<tr>
<th><font size=6 color="rgb(0,0,51)"><a href="chronology.html" style="text-decoration: none">~text~</a></font></th>
<th><font size=6 color="rgb(0,0,51)"><a href="rating & rules.html" style="text-decoration: none">~text</a></font></th>
<th><font size=6 color="rgb(0,0,51)"><a href="techniques.html" style="text-decoration: none">~text</a></font></th>
<th><font size=6 color="rgb(0,0,51)"><a href="greekathletes.html" style="text-decoration: none">~text~</a></font></th>
<th><font size=6 color="rgb(0,0,51)"><a href="contact.html" style="text-decoration: none">~text~</a></font></th>
</tr>
</table>
<img src="left1.png" align="left">
<img src="right1.png" align="right">
<br><br>
<h1 align="center">~text~</h1>
<div align="center">
<video src="Κρίκοι - Εισαγωγή.mp4" width="1000" height="600" controls autoplay>
</div>
<br><br><br>
<p align="center"><font size="4">
~~text~~
</p>
<p align="center">
~~text~~
</p>
</font>
<img src="1.jpg" hspace="200" vspace="20">
<img src="2.png" vspace="20">
<img src="3.jpg" hspace="290" vspace="30">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at your code? My crystal ball is in the shop so it would be helpful if you could add a [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just added it replacing the real text with "~~text~~".

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are only tied to each other with W3C specifications and the heavy use of the `<font>` tag which is not available with HTML5, will cause them to be all over the place, and possibly barely supporting a dusty old tag that no one uses anymore.

It is nearly impossible to develop a good webpage without learning both HTML and CSS. CSS is where you would set your typography.

Grab a good introductory book and get started learning. Both HTML and basic CSS have fairly easy on-ramps.  But if you don't go at it with a bit of training and structure, it will be an exercise in frustration.